# oder by nulls first in descending order in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I  want to order my data in Django admin in descending order, but I want the null field which represent task that has not ended to come to the top first following the descending order of dates.

**for Example**

**End date is listed like this**

--

Dec 5 ,2018

March 2,2017

**and not like this**

Dec 5 ,2018

March 2,2017

--

in my **view.py** I have tried in this way

```
class TaskViewset(Viewsets.ModelViewset)
queryset = Task.objects.filter(end_date__isnull=True).order_by("-end_date")
```

This limit what was return back to only data where end_date is null.

How can i do this to return data including those Task that have ended while returning the not ended task first?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values)

> Using F() to sort null values
>
> Use F() and the nulls_first or nulls_last keyword argument to
> Expression.asc() or desc() to control the ordering of a field’s null
> values. By default, the ordering depends on your database.
>
> For example, to sort companies that haven’t been contacted
> (last_contacted is null) after companies that have been contacted:
>
> ```
> from django.db.models import F 
> Company.objects.order_by(F('last_contacted').desc(nulls_last=True))
> ```

Comment: Thank you iklinac, but in my admin.py i have a class that is using ordering. The changes from your answer does not apply yet because of the ordering in the admin.py, do you have any suggestion on how to adjust this? the following is the code in the admin.py  `class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ("-end_date",)`   that need adjustment in the ordering field.

Comment: ordering in view does not have nothing with ordering in admin site, your question was related to order in view

Comment: Yes you are right. view work now but  in the admin the way it was ordered in view is not ordered that way in admin. The answer is correct in handling view, just want to know how it can be rectify with the admin. Thanks alot if you have any suggestion pls dont hesitate to share.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering